# Extend Date Class in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to have a new method for Date class in my Ruby 2.0 Rails 4 application. Adding a new like 'date_extensions.rb' in /lib used to work in another Ruby 1.9 Rails 3.2 app but not here. The extension is pretty simple now:

```
class Date
  def week_day
    self.wday == 0 ? 7 : self.wday
  end
end
```

I do not like to put it in initializer as it keeps growing. Is there a good workaround?

Comment: What's wrong with a `require 'date_extensions'` one-liner in `config/initializers/`?

Comment: If you have a lot of data related methods consider moving them to a Gem.

Comment: mu is too short: yes, that's not wrong. But I'm wondering why even such an initializer is not needed in Ruby1.9 or Rails3.2. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

At some point, Rails stopped adding the `lib` directory to the autoload paths. The other app had probably set a setting to autoload the `lib` directory and your new app doesn't have that (yet?). So that's why you're having to require the file directly via an initializer. For what it's worth: I think this is the better approach -- only load code when you need it. I usually add a `config/initializers/application.rb` and then add requires such as `require "date_extensions"` in there. Then the date_extensions.rb file goes in the lib folder as you suggest.